# apk running on AVD but not on phone

Tags: java, android

My `compileSdkVersion` is 26
`minSdkVersion` is 15
and `TargetSdkVersion` is 26

App runs fine on AVD of API level 22 but when installed on phone and opened it shows "Unfortunately APP has stopped". My phone is running in jellybean.

Comment: post your logcat.

Comment: You'll have to look at logcat to see what exact error occurred.

Comment: @e-LogicSense logcat is empty...app runs perfectly on AVD but when exported as APK using build apk option and then installed on phone i get the error

Comment: try to debug the code to find the cause of error.

Comment: If it shows "App has stopped", there should be a crash stack trace in Logcat. Please take a look again.

Comment: @VadimKotov app is getting crashed on exported as apk in and installed on phone. how do i check the logcat in phone??

Comment: Connect your device to the Android Studio and run your app. Please take a look at https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html

Comment: Also https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#RunningApp

Comment: You should provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to the community here to be able to answer your question without guessing. This includes relevant logcat output and relevant code.

Comment: UPDATED CODE SHOWING THE LOGCAT

Comment: Looks like there is no crash log in here. Please provide relevant portion or full logcat output. Also take a look at answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35092294/debug-android-app-crash-no-info-in-logcat-no-info-in-console-when-attached

Comment: @VadimKotov so sorry could not provide you the crash report. I am a newbie actually. There was a memory error in the crash report so i reduced the dimensions of the image and now the app works fine. Thank you for your time

Comment: @AbhijitBorkakoty No problem, glad it is resolved. Study the docs for the tools you're using - it will be easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a memory error when tested on debugging mode. I reduced the dimensions of the image and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your access any permission in your application. You should ask permission in runtime as well as in manifest file

Comment: export your debug-app in your mobile and connect  your mobile to your pc, you will get the logcat

Answer (score 0):

If you are using below 6.0 version you don't need to write permission at runtime but you have to mention in manifest.

Maybe you have use third party library which is not supported in your device.